# private build information (db, etc) when making a release in maven?

Tags: hibernate, maven, maven-release-plugin

How do I keep stuff hidden from my developers when I want to release?

For example - when the time comes to release, I am going to want to create a hibernate session with different settings - the settings to the DB that runs in the life environment.

How do I specify these during maven-release, in a manner such that they are not visible to anyone else?

I was thinking maybe the command-line when building, setting a property of some sort? How is this typically done in an enterprise scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a separate maven [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for your Dev, QA and Release environments which can be invoked using  -P option to mvn command. Following is some sample profile  snippet that needs to included in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <hostEnv>QA</hostEnv>
    <hostDB>oracle</hostDB>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>${hostEnv}-${hostDB}</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                            ...                 
        </activation>       
</profile>      
</profiles>
```

Comment: I'm staying away from activeByDefault - but - would I be able to encrypt what I put in the password field with maven pw encryption?

Comment: You can encrypt the password using some ant script which can be invoked with help from maven-antrun-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Things like passwords etc. belong to the settings.xml and not into the pom.xml file. Furthermore i would suggest to put such things into the settings.xml on a continious integration server like Jenkins etc. The approach to put that only on the build machine prevents others from accidently creating releases.